# C# Code optimization causes problems with Interlocked.Exchange()

Tags: c#, optimization, release, interlocked

I have a frustrating problem with a bit of code and don't know why this problem occurs.

```cs
//
// .NET FRAMEWORK v4.6.2 Console App

static void Main( string[] args )
{
    var list = new List<string>{ "aa", "bbb", "cccccc", "dddddddd", "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee", "fffff", "gg" };

    foreach( var item in list )
    {
        Progress( item );
    }
}

private static int _cursorLeft = -1;
private static int _cursorTop = -1;
public static void Progress( string value = null )
{
    lock( Console.Out )
    {
        if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( value ) )
        {
            Console.Write( value );
            var left = Console.CursorLeft;
            var top = Console.CursorTop;
            Interlocked.Exchange( ref _cursorLeft, Console.CursorLeft );
            Interlocked.Exchange( ref _cursorTop, Console.CursorTop );
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine( "Left: {0} _ {1}", _cursorLeft, left );
            Console.WriteLine( "Top: {0} _ {1}", _cursorTop, top );
        }
    }
}
```

When running **without** *Code optimization* then the result is as expected. *_cursorLeft* and *left* as far as *_cursorTop* and *top* are equal.

```
aa
Left: 2 _ 2
Top: 0 _ 0
bbb
Left: 3 _ 3
Top: 3 _ 3
```

But when I run it **with** *Code optimization* both values *_cursorLeft* and *_cursorTop* become bizzare:

```
aa
Left: -65534 _ 2
Top: -65536 _ 0
bb
Left: -65533 _ 3
Top: -65533 _ 3
```

I found out 2 workarounds:

1. set *_cursorLeft* and *_cursorTop* to **0** instead of -1
2. let Interlocked.Exchange take the value from *left* resp. *top*

Because workaround #1 does not match my needs I ended up with workaround #2:

```cs
private static int _cursorLeft = -1;
private static int _cursorTop = -1;
public static void Progress( string value = null )
{
    lock( Console.Out )
    {
        if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( value ) )
        {
            Console.Write( value );

            // OLD - does NOT work!
            //Interlocked.Exchange( ref _cursorLeft, Console.CursorLeft );
            //Interlocked.Exchange( ref _cursorTop, Console.CursorTop );

            // NEW - works great!
            var left = Console.CursorLeft;
            var top = Console.CursorTop;
            Interlocked.Exchange( ref _cursorLeft, left );  // new
            Interlocked.Exchange( ref _cursorTop, top );  // new
        }
    }
}
```

But where does this bizarre behavior comes from?
And is there a better workaround/solution?

---

**[Edit by Matthew Watson: Adding simplified repro:]**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int actual = -1;
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref actual, Test.AlwaysReturnsZero);
        Console.WriteLine("Actual value: {0}, Expected 0", actual);
    }
}

static class Test
{
    static short zero;
    public static int AlwaysReturnsZero => zero;
}
```

---

**[Edit by me:]**
I figured out another even shorter example:

```
class Program
{
    private static int _intToExchange = -1;
    private static short _innerShort = 2;

    // [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var oldValue = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _intToExchange, _innerShort);
        Console.WriteLine( "It was:   {0}", oldValue );
        Console.WriteLine( "It is:    {0}", _intToExchange );
        Console.WriteLine( "Expected: {0}", _innerShort );
    }
}
```

Unless you don't use *Optimization* or set *_intToExchange* to a value in the range of `ushort` you would not recognize the problem.

Comment: I can reproduce this.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a simplified repro.You may incorporate it or delete it as you see fit.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Good idea! I really thought it has to be a specific problem but it seems like a big bug.

Comment: I have reported this issue here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3131687/incorrect-code-generated-by-64-bit-jitter-ryujit-for-call-to-interlocked-exchange

Comment: It should be fixed in the future: github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10714

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You diagnosed the problem correctly, this is an optimizer bug.  It is specific to the 64-bit jitter (aka RyuJIT), the one that first started shipping in VS2015.  You can only see it by looking at the generated machine code.  Looks like this on my machine:

```
00000135  movsx       rcx,word ptr [rbp-7Ch]       ; Cursor.Left
0000013a  mov         r8,7FF9B92D4754h             ; ref _cursorLeft
00000144  xchg        cx,word ptr [r8]             ; Interlocked.Exchange
```

The XCHG instruction is wrong, it uses 16-bit operands (cx and word ptr).  But the variable type requires 32-bit operands.  As a consequence, the upper 16-bits of the variable remain at 0xffff, making the entire value negative.

Characterizing this bug is a bit tricky, it is not easy to isolate.  Getting the Cursor.Left property getter inlined appears to be instrumental to trigger the bug, under the hood it accesses a 16-bit field.  Apparently enough to, somehow, make the optimizer decide that a 16-bit exchange will get the job done.  And the reason why your workaround code solved it, using 32-bit variables to store the Cursor.Left/Top properties bumps the optimizer into a good codepath.

The workaround in this case is a pretty simple one, beyond the one you found, you don't need Interlocked at all because the `lock` statement already makes the code thread-safe.  Please report the bug at connect.microsoft.com, let me know if you don't want to take the time and I'll take care of it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson  Okay

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this in .net core, did you try to do that?

Comment: I didn't.  Not likely to repro, making the Console class cross-platform so it can run on Linux and OSX surely prevents the property from being easy to inline.

Comment: But you can reproduce this issue with just method with return type int but which internally returns short, without any access to Console class at all.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an exact explanation, but still would like to share my findings. It seems to be a bug in x64 jitter inlining in combination with `Interlocked.Exchange` which is implemented in native code. Here is a short version to reproduce, without using `Console` class.

```
class Program {
    private static int _intToExchange = -1;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        _innerShort = 2;
        var left = GetShortAsInt();
        var oldLeft = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _intToExchange, GetShortAsInt());
        Console.WriteLine("Left: new {0} current {1} old {2}", _intToExchange, left, oldLeft);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static short _innerShort;
    static int GetShortAsInt() => _innerShort;
}
```

So we have an `int` field and a method which returns `int` but really returns 'short' (just like `Console.LeftCursor` does). If we compile this in release mode with optimizations AND for x64, it will output:

```
new -65534 current 2 old 65535
```

What happens is jitter inlines `GetShortAsInt` but doing so somehow incorrectly. I'm not really sure about why exactly things go wrong. EDIT: as Hans points out in his answer - optimizer uses incorrect `xchg` instuction in this case to perform as exchange.

If you change like this:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
static int GetShortAsInt() => _innerShort;
```

It will work as expected:

```
new 2 current 2 old -1
```

With non-negative values it seems to work at first site, but really does not - when `_intToExchange` exceeds `ushort.MaxValue` - it breaks again:

```
private static int _intToExchange = ushort.MaxValue + 2;
new 65538 current 2 old 1
```

So given all this - your workaround looks fine.

Comment: Maybe it would be an good idea to check if this is still happening with .net core and then report it on github, because this seems like a really weird bug.

Comment: Another "workaround" for your example is:  `static int GetShortAsInt() => Convert.ToInt32(_innerShort);`

Comment: Okay, one more workaround: remove `_innerShort = 2;` and set `private static short _innerShort = 2;`

Comment: @Ronin I specifically crafted this example for it to NOT work correctly :)

Comment: @Evk I absolutely know. I just wanted to report the strange behavior.

Comment: @Staeff I was not able to reproduce it in .net core.

Comment: @Evk you need to set `<Optimize>true<Optimize>` and `<DebugType></DebugType>` in the .csproj file to reproduce it